# Drift velocity and temperature

Tags: electricity, electric-current

How does drift velocity vary with temperature? Does it increase or decrease?

Comment: Depends on the temperature and the material and the defect denisty of the material etc etc. Be more specific to your situation.

Comment: I mean to say that all other conditions are unaltered. Only temperature of the conductor is increased. Then will drift velocity decrease?

Answer (score 2):

In typical electrical conductors (metals or semiconductors) around room temperature, the drift velocity of the conduction electrons $v$, which at low electric fields $E$ is proportional to the electric field strength $$v=\mu E$$ ($\mu$ is the mobility) *decreases with increasing temperature*. This is due to the increase of scattering of the electrons by the vibrations (phonons) of the crystal lattice.

Answer (score 0):

The mobility ($\mu$) versus temperature curve has a single point of maxima, hence it is increasing in some places and decreasing in others. The value of temperature where mobility ($\mu$) achieves its maxima is a function of the material that you are talking about[Look at this for example.](http://www.ioffe.ru/SVA/NSM/Semicond/InN/figs/chin941a.gif)

And of course the classical transport model holds

$$\vec{v_d}=\mu \vec{E}$$, but $\mu$'s temperature dependance has material dependance embedded into it. Also the individual temperature matters, because there are points of maxima in there. It's like saying will the function $$f(x)=\sin{(ax+b)}$$ increase or decrease with $x$. Depends on $x$ and also on the parameters $a$ and $b$. In your question, for example $x$ is the temperature and $a$ and $b$ are material constants.

Comment: who downvoted this answer and can you explain why??